# Best way to backup nextcloud with multiple users and only remote (webdav, client) access?

Tags: backup, webdav, nextcloud

I have an externally hosted nextcloud for which I have admin access but no access to the server (no ssh etc). There are multiple users but family only - so assume all user passwords are known. The hoster only keeps backups for 7 days and i would like to keep daily or weekly snapshots for a longer time and maintain a local backup.

What is the best backup solution for this?
It should reliably backup all data in the cloud and be resource efficient.

I could davfs mount the nextcloud, but webdav seems to be tricky with time stamps, so not sure how good this is for backup?
I am thinking to just run a nextcloud client on some small server that syncs with all accounts and then just do incremental backups of the local nextcloud folder with Borg.
Is there a better way to do this?